# changing uinavigationBar multiple background iOS 4.3

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

i used to use the code below to change the UINavigationBar Background :

the CODE:

```
    - (void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"NavBar.png"];
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
}
```

so now i need more than one background NavBar2.png ....

how to achieve this ?

Thanks

Comment: Did you set a tag for each navigation bar and tried that?

Comment: @R.A NO, how i can get the take in the above method ?

Comment: set tag for each navigation bar in XIB and put an if condition to check the navigationBar.tag and set different image in each if condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it by using my original code as image background then put `titleView` for the navigation bar

```
UIView *aView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 165, 44)];
    UIImageView *imgv = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:aView.frame];
    imgv.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"NavBar01.png"];
    [aView addSubview:imgv];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.titleView =  aView;
    [aView release];
    [imgv release];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
- (void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
if(navigationBar.tag == 0){
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"NavBar.png"];
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
}
else if(navigationBar.tag == 1)
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"NavBar1.png"];
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tag logic mentioned by R.A. would definitely help you.

If you are developing an app on iOS5, then you can also take a look at :

```
- (void)setBackgroundImage:(UIImage *)backgroundImage forBarMetrics:(UIBarMetrics)barMetrics
```